# How to compute CSS `top` value without Javascript for a sticky table header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do away with `top:50px` in a sticky table header bar, where 50px refers to the height of a sticky action bar.

I could use JavaScript to compute the height of the action bar and apply it in inline CSS using a JavaScript framework, but I would prefer to use CSS and leave the 50px to be computed with CSS. Is this possible?

I know that I can use CSS variables to fix the 50px, but I would prefer the height to be dynamically computed based on the content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
  minimum-height: 100vh;
}

#first_bar {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
}

#second_bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
}

#other_content {
  background: grey;
}

#table_header {
  position: sticky;
  width: 200vw;
  top: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

#large_table {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first_bar">navigation</div>
  <div id="second_bar">action bar</div>
  <div id="other_content">other content</div>
  <div id="table_header">table header</div>
  <div id="large_table">table</div>
</div>
```

I would have to position the table header below the action bar when the large table starts to scroll vertically and the other content disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you want, i assume you need to use [css variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)

```
:root {
--variableName: 50px 
--colorName: #141414
}
```

Comment: Thank you @almaszosz, I would like the height to be computed somehow after the bars are filled with elements. So that the design can be responsive, for example if a user makes the elements wrap inside or the bar and the height increases dynamically. When fixing a CSS variable this is not possible.